# White noise on audio setup for two computers

Tags: noise

I'm having trouble with a streaming setup, consisting of two computers.

To listen to both the audio from the Streaming PC, and the Gaming PC; the Streaming PC has been plugged in to a Sound Blaster Card, and the gaming PC is connected to that with a Jack Cable in the line in.

However there is white noise from the Gaming PC, it does not happen if I plug in an iPhone, only the Gaming PC. I tried adding a ROCCAT® Juke to the gaming machine as I was thinking it was the motherboard that had noise, however this did nothing.

What could possibly create this noise?

Roccat: https://www.roccat.org/en-US/Products/Gaming-Sound/Juke/
Sound Blaster Card: https://us.creative.com/p/sound-blaster/sound-blaster-x-fi-surround-5-1-pro

Answer (score 2):

Lucas points out one key issue, but there is another possible issue as well.  Grounding levels can differ if the computers are plugged in to different circuits or if they have poor internal grounding that changes the relative ground.  In the case that this occurs, you will get a buzz that matches up with the frequency of your power (either 50hz or 60hz depending on where you are located) known as ground differential.  If this is what is occurring, your best bet is to used a device called a direct box and apply what is known as a "ground lift" which should isolate the ground and remove the ground differential.

Answer (score 1):

The Line-In is designed to **receive** an audio signal at a line level (usually stereo and about 10Kohm impedance) **not sending audio**.

You must route the audio of your Gaming PC to your Soundcard with a **mini-jack (3.5mm) pluged in the Line-Out** (often green) **of your PC to any analogic input of your soundcard (you can use an adapter if your soundcard currently doesn't have a free mini-Jack input).

Comment: This is how it is setup, from the computers Line-Out to the soundcards Line-In. So it seems correct, right?

Comment: The soundcard is in the streaming computer though, right? And you want the sound out of the gaming computer, right? Then you have it in reverse. It should be line-out on soundcard to line-in of gaming comp. If i'm reading that wrong and you want the streaming computer playing the sound, then you have it right.

Comment: Actually, i don't see you mention which computer has the speakers attached, and that would help